# Instance into list from two classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am using C#, Visual Studio 2015.

How do I add these two accounts (same person) from the form load?

Example Data to add:

Bob Smith 1/1/1970 
(account):123456 (balance):$5000  and (account):222222 and (balance):$3000?

Here is part of the BankAccount class:

```
        public int AccountNumber { get; private set; }
        public double Balance { get; private set; }

        public BankAccount()
        {
            this.AccountNumber = generateAccountNumber();
            this.Balance = 0;
        }


        public BankAccount(Wallet accounts)
        {
            this.AccountNumber = generateAccountNumber();
            this.Balance = 0;
            this.AccountNumber = Convert.ToInt16(accounts.AccountList);     
        }

        public BankAccount(double beginningBalance)
        {
            Balance = beginningBalance;
        }

        private int generateAccountNumber()
        {
            Random numGenerator = new Random();
            //Requirement: 6 digit account number, cannot start with zero
            return numGenerator.Next(100000, 999999);
        }
```

and this is some of the Wallet class:

```
private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private DateTime birthDate;
        private List<BankAccount> accountList = new List<BankAccount>();

        public Wallet(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime birth, List<BankAccount> Account)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.birthDate = birth;
            this.accountList = Account;
        }

        public List<BankAccount> AccountList
        {
            get { return accountList; }
            set { accountList = value; }
        }
```

QUESTION:  How do I create two accounts (from same person) to already be there?

Comment: I'd suggest you revise your question, it's difficult to follow.

Comment: Alright... I did, though not sure it helped...

Comment: First you should know HOW and WHERE to store your data. It can be a database, file, etc. Next, you should know WHEN to load your data.

Comment: This line makes no sense: `this.AccountNumber = Convert.ToInt16(accounts.AccountList);  `

Comment: Evan:  Could you be more specific?

Comment: How would you convert a list of bank accounts to an int? What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two classes in your question not only create a reference with each other (bank account knows wallet and wallet knows bank account), but also have no `public` way to set up the data as per your requirements: you can't create a `BankAccount` and define both person and balance.

Instead, try something like this - obviously violating some of your other requirements, but solving your question around creating the correct instances:

```
public BankAccount
{
    public Wallet Account { get; private set; } // reference to the person
    public int AccountNumber { get; private set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; private set; }

    public BankAccount(Wallet account)
    {
        this.AccountNumber = GenerateAccountNumber();
        this.Balance = 0; // always zero to start with
        this.Account = account; // check to be NOT null or bank account may have no account
    }

    public void TransferMoney(decimal amount)
    {
        this.Balance += amount;
    }

    private int GenerateAccountNumber()
    {
        return new Random().Next(100000, 999999);
    }
}
```

The `Wallet` class should not reference the bank accounts! If you need to know what bank accounts are owned by who just check on them rather than keeping references:

```
public class Wallet
{
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private DateTime birthDate;
    // don't keep a reference here. Bank accounts already know their accounts
    // private List<BankAccount> accountList = new List<BankAccount>();

    public Wallet(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime birth)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthDate = birth;
    }
}
```

And this is how you set up you sample scenario. As the account number is random you cannot specify it unless you change your code.

```
Wallet account = new Wallet("Bob", "Smith", ...);
BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount(account);
account1.TransferMoney(5000);
BankAccount account2 = new BankAccount(account);
account2.TransferMoney(3000);
```